# SLURM / Sbatch creates many small output files

Tags: slurm, snakemake, sbatch

I am running a pipeline on a SLURM-cluster, and for some reason a lot of smaller files (between 500 and 2000 bytes in size) named along the lines of `slurm-XXXXXX.out` (where `XXXXXX` is a number). I've tried to find out what these files are on the SLURM website, but I can't find any mention of them. I assume they are some sort of in-progress files that the system uses while parsing my pipeline?

If it matters, the pipeline I'm running is using `snakemake`. I know I've seen these types of files before though, without `snakemake`, but I they weren't a big problem back then. I'm afraid that clearing the working directory of these files after each step of the workflow will interrupt in-progress steps, so I'm not doing anything with them at the moment.

What are these files, and how can I suppress their output or, alternatively, delete them after their corresponding job is finished? Did I mess up my workflow somehow, and that's why they are created?

Comment: I guess that your snakemake workflow submits a lot of jobs to the cluster, each one generating one of these files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [sbatch](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) documentation.  The files that you are referring to are essentially SLURM logs as explained there:

> By default both standard output and standard error are directed to a
>   file of the name "slurm-%j.out", where the "%j" is replaced with the
>   job allocation number.

You can change the filename with the `--error=<filename pattern>` and `--output=<filename pattern>` command line options.  The filename_pattern can have one or more symbols that will be replaced as explained in the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#lbAF).  According to the [FAQs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#terminal), you should be able to suppress standard output and standard error by using the following command line options:

`sbatch --output=/dev/null --error=/dev/null [...]`

Comment: Oh, that's great! I don't know how I missed that... Thanks for the help :-)